# E-Commencement solution for Sitecore and Microsoft CRM

Tags: e-commerce, dynamics-crm-2011, sitecore, cots

I've started at an organisation that is moving towards Sitecore CMS and Microsoft CRM for various reasons. They have an extremely old "shop" website which they are looking at replacing this with a COTS product.

Does anyone have experience with an e-commence product which works well with either SiteCore or CRM. (I don't have a lot of experience on the e-commence side, so I don't know who the big players in the industry are...)

Sorry if this is off-topic, I did check that http://webapps.stackexchange.com and http://programmers.stackexchange.com and this seemed like the most logical place this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used Insite Commerce for one of client's eCommerce Project. Found it pretty seamless*. Insite also has tight integration with Microsoft Dynamics GP. Insite for Sitecore module comes for free with Sitecore but I must mention that there is absolutely no support available from Insite unless you pay them.

*If you plan to go this route, I'd recommend taking Insite training to better understand their commerce engine.

Answer (score 2):

Active Commerce has also been developing an OOTB eCommerce solution based on the Sitecore eCommerce module: http://www.activecommerce.com/

It has some pretty slick out of the box product catalog stuff when I was shown their demo, and the UI customization is easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore has an E-commerce module.  I recommend you start there. http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/SEFE.aspx